# "Big Dipper" operation -- does this operation have a name?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

Seth Warner, in his "Modern Algebra" (1965) introduces the reader to the following mapping on $N_{<(m+n)}$ where $N_{<(m+n)} := \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, m+n-1\}$:

$$\forall a, b \in N_{<(m+n)}: a +_{m, n} b = \begin {cases} a + b & : a + b < m \\ a + b - k n & : a + b \ge m \end{cases}$$
where $k$ is the largest integer such that $m + k n \le a + b$.

For context and comprehension, this is the Cayley table for $+_{3, 4}$:

$$\begin{array}{r|rrrrrrr}
+_{3, 4} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6
\\
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 3
\\
2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 3 & 4
\\
3 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 3 & 4 & 5
\\
4 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6
\\
5 & 5 & 6 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 3
\\
6 & 6 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 3 & 4
\\
\end{array}$$

Warner suggests an analogy with the "big dipper", identifying the stars along the handle starting at $0$, stepping along the handle and then round the pan.

I have therefore been referring to this operation as the "big dipper operation" and thought no more about it, but it turns out it is a fundamental concept in defining what is known as a *strictly inductive semigroup*. (We encounter these in the exercises for Section $16$ in the same text.)

Later in that same (section $16$) set of exercises, he refers to a semigroup isomorphic to $(N_{<(m+n)}, +_{m, n})$ as a "dipper", clearly with that same celestial constellation in mind.

But the question needs to be asked: is there an "official" name for this operation? If I call it the "big dipper operation" or "dipper operation" (assuming I define it when I use it), am I going to be laughed at?

Comment: I don't know of a standard name for it, but this is just addition in the finite semiring $\mathbb{N}/(n\mathbb{N}+m)$. Two extremal cases which do have common names are $m=0$ (addition modulo $n$) and $m=n=1$ (Boolean disjunction).

Comment: @Servaes Apologies, I have corrected the definition. Should have been largest integer $k$ such that $m + kn  \le a + b$.

Comment: @Thissitehasbecomeadump. Concerning your username: Happens to every q/a forum in the end. The best questions are asked, and all that's left is latecomers and underachievers like me who ask the mathematical equivalent of "Is it true that [celebrity] has boils on their [body part]?" Happened to mathhelpforum which was excellent 15 years ago, it's happened to Quora (as noted), and so on and so forth. Fun places to play are few and far between, and most are run by joyless anti-banter puritans who punish irreverence with an eternal ban.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Seth Warner himself may well have coined the name **dipper operation**, as he raises the subject in a 1960 article:

> "Mathematical Induction in Commutative Semigroups", Seth Warner, *The American Mathematical Monthly* Vol. 67, No. 6 (Jun. - Jul., 1960), pp. 533-537 (5 pages)

"We shall say a semigroup $D$ is a *dipper semigroup* if it is isomorphic either with $D (n, m)$ or $D^* (n, m)$ ..."